# Getting unwanted " " between words when appending a CSV file to a new CSV file in Python 3

Tags: python, csv, python-3.7

I'm trying to append a CSV file to a new CSV file, and where there were no "" between the words in my first document, i get those when appending it to the new file. Example :

```
house
building 
apartment
loan
```

is how is the CSV file I want to import. I wrote this code :

```
import csv 

csv_file = open("bigcsv.csv", "a", encoding='utf-8', newline = "")
csv_file_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter= ",")

document_to_append = open("test.csv", "r")
for row in document_to_append:
    print(row)
    csv_file_writer.writerow([row])

document_to_append.close()
csv_file.close()
```

And the result in CSV is this :

```
"house
"
"building
"
```

and so on…

How can I get rid of those annoying ""? I have absolutely no idea…

Comment: I think it is the spaces and the quotes are coming to next line..try trimming spaces and try...It will work

Comment: What happens if you get rid of the last item of row ? csv_file_writer.writerow([row[:-1]])

Comment: It works with csv_file_writer.writerow([row[:-1]]), I Don't understand why but ok. If you can explain it's perfect (for my knowledge), thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the reason, but I think it's because you're turning row into a list in the line `csv_file_writer.writerow([row])` I'd use this below:

```
import csv 

with open("bigcsv.csv", "r") csv_file:
with open("test.csv", "w") as csv_file_writer:
    for row in csv_file:
        csv_file_writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: If I remove the list, it's writing a coma between every letter

Answer (score 0):

You can set the csv.writer to quote nothing with quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE like below:

```
import csv
csv_file = open("bigcsv.csv", "a", encoding='utf-8', newline = "")
csv_file_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter= ",", escapechar=' ',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,lineterminator='')
document_to_append = open("test.csv", "r")
for row in document_to_append:
    print(row)
    csv_file_writer.writerow([row])
document_to_append.close()
csv_file.close()
```

Demo Link:

> https://repl.it/repls/FarLopsidedBaitware

Answer (score 0):

replace the line:

```
document_to_append = open("test.csv", "r")
```

by:

```
document_to_append = [line.rstrip() for line in open('test.csv', "r")]
```

Note: this will work but you would have to remove the line: *document_to_append.close()* as *document_to_append* is no longer a handle, but a list.

If you want to **close** the file anyhow, then instead of list comprehension(the above solution), do this:

```
with open('test.csv') as f:
    document_to_append = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
```